# angular 7 http post work on edge and firefox but return error on chrome

Tags: angular, http-post

http post not work on chrome browser , but work fine on firefox and edge

i have an application with angular7 and netcore 2.2 , crud example work fine in all browser except save method (that have http.post) not work on chrome

```
 save(user: UserModel): Observable<ResponseObj> {
    const body =   JSON.stringify(user);
    const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post("/api/Users/Save", body, options)
      .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

i expected call server api and create new user

Comment: Could you add screenshot for error that appears in chrome?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Please clear your cache in chrome

Comment: this is appeared error   : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return this._http.post("/api/Users/Save", body, options)
    .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        }, error => {
            this.handleError
        }
     )
```